# Как отфильтровать строку от sql инъекций без подготовленных запросов?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Мне известно, что при использовании неподготовленных запросов к БД, в случае вставки определенных символов, эти запросы можно скомпрометировать.

Меня интересует, какие символы нужно удалить из POST/GET входящих данных, чтобы гарантированно не пропустить SQL-инъекцию? Какой набор операций применить к строке? Достаточно ли `htmlspecialchars` и `addslashes`? Почему информация, касающаяся этого вопроса, столь расплывчата и сводится к PDO?

Comment: Что не удобного в `$pdo->prepare("select x from table where y=:y")->execute([ 'y' => $y ])` ? Кроме того вокруг функций с подготовленными запросами всегда можно сделать подходящие обертки, работающие например как `$result = $db->select_row("select x from tab where y=:y", [ 'y' => $y ])`

Comment: А так то вообще надо заэкранировать кавычки, обратную косую и все управляющие символы. htmlspecialchars вообще не имеет отношения к sql. Но ведь помимо инъекций подготовленные выражения помогают в передаче двоичных данных, уменьшают потенциальные проблемы с кодировками, увеличивают быстродействие, для некоторых БД (к mysql отношения не имеет), позволяют избегать повторной компиляции запросов, снижают отравление кеша запросов

Comment: Если один из ответов Вам помог, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов этого ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Тут важно понимать правильный ответ на поставленный вопрос.

> Меня интересует, какие символы нужно удалить из post/get входящих данных  чтобы гарантированно не пропустить sql инъекцию?

**Никакие.**

Гарантированно не пропустить sql инъекцию таким способом **невозможно**.

Много лет назад в РНР уже была функциональность, которая делала именно это. Называлась "волшебные кавычки". Как выяснилось, гарантированно они только портили входящие данные, а от инъекций не защищали от слова "совсем". В итоге волшебные кавычки с ужасом выкинули из языка.

И этому есть одно простое объяснение.
Дело в том, что хотя большинство хомячков до сих пор верят, что удаление или экранирование каких-либо сиволов защищает их от SQL инъекций, **на самом деле это не так**. Экранирование вообще не имеет отношения к инъекциям. И никогда не должно применяться для защиты. И удаление любых символов тоже только гарантированно испортит входящие данные, но не защитит от возможнйо инъекции.

Что гарантированно защищает - это когда в SQL запрос **вообще не попадают никакие данные**, а передаются отдельно от запроса. И это достигается с помощью использования подготовленных выражений.

Никаких сложностей, кроме лени и невежества, при использовании подготовленных запросов нет. Это ничуть не сложнее той кривизны, котору ты уже успел освоить.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from table where id=?");
$stmt->execute([$id]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

три несчастные строчки.

или, если надо получить несколько строк, то *четыре*

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from table where id > ?");
$stmt->execute([$id]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
}
```

Comment: Со всем согласен, кроме вот этого: "Экранирование ... никогда не должно применяться для защиты". При всей потенциальной ненадёжности такого подхода, он возможен и применяем. Конечно, Вы можете иметь особое мнение, но security community - это чуть больше, чем Вы. И они приводят данный метод, как один из возможных, хотя наименее приоритетный. А чтоб Вам веселее было, подскажите как использовать методику подготовленного запроса для такого `alter table test add column ? int`, здесь переменная - имя столбца

Comment: Специально для идолопоклонников. Экранирование применяется для обработки специальных символов в строковых литералах SQL. Эта формулировка принципиально, диаметрально отличается от хомячкового заклинания "экранирование входящих данных применяется для защиты от инъекций". И это отличие как раз составляет разницу между энаниями и суеверием, между  защитой и дырами величиной с пробоину титаника

Comment: Отличие между "экранирование входящих данных применяется для защиты от инъекций" и "экранирование входящих данных может применяться для защиты от инъекций" - это отличие между знаниями и суеверием.

Answer (score 0):

### Сначала отвечу на вопрос:

> Меня интересует, какие символы нужно удалить из post/get входящих данных, чтобы гарантированно не пропустить sql инъекцию?

Никакие. Не надо ничего удалять, так как Вам придется писать вариант искусственного интеллекта, чтобы не удалить что-то важное. И все равно оно удалит...

> Какой набор операций применить к строке?

При включённом SQL mode `ANSI`, достаточно закодировать все одинарные кавычки `'` двумя одинарными кавычками `''`

В остальных случаях, кодируются символы:

```
NUL (0x00) --> \0  [Здесь ноль, а не буква О]
BS  (0x08) --> \b
TAB (0x09) --> \t
LF  (0x0a) --> \n
CR  (0x0d) --> \r
SUB (0x1a) --> \Z
"   (0x22) --> \"
%   (0x25) --> \%
'   (0x27) --> \'
\   (0x5c) --> \\
_   (0x5f) --> \_ 
все не буквенно-цифровые символы с ASCII значениями < 256 --> \c
где `c` это кодируемый символ
```

Источник: [SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md)

---

### А теперь то, что важно помнить:

В том же источнике сказано:

> Кодирование ввода должно использоваться только в самом крайнем случае, когда использование других техник защиты неоправданно. Данная методика очень хрупкая и ненадёжная по сравнению с другими, и невозможно гарантировать, что она предотвратит все случаи SQL Injection во всех ситуациях.

Более предпочтительные техники защиты:

1. Подготовленные выражения (с параметрическими запросами)
2. Хранимые процедуры
3. Проверка ввода по белому списку

Comment: Этот ответ не учитывает контекст вопроса. "какие символы нужно удалить *из post/get входящих данных*".

Comment: @Ипатьев Ну-ну. Как удалятели понаписывают кода, так потом что-то нужное и правильное - фиг введешь, понимаешь ли какой-нибудь процент им на инъекцию похож...

Comment: @Ипатьев Сейчас ответ учитывает контекст вопроса. И является полностью верным, хотя и менее эмоциональным, чем Ваш. Предлагаю Вам пересмотреть свою оценку